# Global results across different packages defined in struts configuration file

Tags: java, struts2, config, actionresult

I would like to create a `global-results` across different packages which are under different namespaces. Can I know the conventions that required to follow in struts config file?

Comment: It would be nice if you downvote a question to at least say what's wrong about it.

Comment: @cljk I don't understand your comment, I have *upvoted* this question, and recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define global result in the package that other packages extend. For example

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  ...
  <global-results>
    <result name="error">/pages/error_page.jsp</result>
  </global-results>
  ...
</package>
```

This result could be used across actions that forward to error page and as exception handling result.

If you are using conventions plugin with annotations you could define `@Results` annotation on the class that has the parent package other packages extend. For example

```
@Results({
  @Result(name = ERROR, location = "/pages/error_page.jsp"),
})
```

The parent package is annotated with `@ParentPackage` annotation. It could be placed on the class but better place it on the package. For example

`package-info.java`:

```
@ParentPackage("default")
```