# Can I change the struts.xml file to anything else?

Tags: xml, struts2, xml-configuration

When I'm going though struts2, I came through a typical question.
The question is that can I change the name of `struts.xml` file to some other thing and make it work?

Comment: I don't know if you can, but I also don't see why you'd want or need to.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Just want to know whether that is possible or not as in hibernate. That's it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing struts.xml file name for a multi-module Maven web project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955487/changing-struts-xml-file-name-for-a-multi-module-maven-web-project)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using your `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>my-new-struts-config-file.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Also, if you use the `struts.properties` you can do something like:

```
struts.configuration.files=my-new-struts-config-file.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml
```

Comment: I tried adding your code to web.xml.But, it isn't working.
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Apr 13, 2014 8:14:41 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed

Comment: What did you use on the param-value? did you try using only the one file you are going to use?... also did you modify the properties file?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the name of struts.xml. You can, however, break up the Struts configuration among several configuration files which are named in strtus.xml.

[For more details see this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/configuration-files.html)