# Login form with MySQL via JDBC: Model driven in Struts 2

Tags: java, mysql, struts2

I am new to struts2. I am using  NetBeans8, Glassfish4 and MySql6.

I am making a login form. The problem I am having is is that I am not getting either an error or any output.

I can run my application and at my login page after clicking on submit nothing happens, but my url changes to `http://localhost:8080/Pharma/loginAction.action`

Please could somebody help, your suggestions would be highly appreciated

LoginAction.java

```
package package_login;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;


public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>{
    User user=new User();

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public User getModel() {   
       return user;
    }
     public void validate(){
     if(StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())){
         addFieldError("email","Please entered your email");
     }

      if(StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getPassword())){
         addFieldError("password","Please entered your password");
     }

     }


    public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        LoginService loginService= new LoginService();
        if(loginService.verifyLogin(user)){
      return "logged";
}
return "login";
}
}
```

LoginService.java

```
package package_login;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


    class LoginService {
        public boolean verifyLogin(User user) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erp","root","ali$");
            Statement st= con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select password,email from login where email='"+user.getEmail()+"'" );
            while(rs.next()){
           //   if(user.getEmail().equals(rs.getString("email"))&& user.getPassword().equals("password")){
            //    return true;
               }
           // }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

User.java

```
package package_login;


class User {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="package_login" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="loginAction" class="package_login.LoginAction">
            <result name="logged">/welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:form action="loginAction">
            <s:textfield key="email" label="Email"/>
            <s:password key="password" label="Password"/>
            <s:submit value="login"/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31490488/573032) answer how to handle parameters in sql/hql queries to avoid security vulnerabilities in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select email from login where email='"+user.getEmail()+"' and password='"+user.getPassword()+"'" );
if(rs.next())
 {
      return true;//if valid user, return true
 }
 else 
 return false;
```

and 
your are using struts configuration file name `login.xml`.

The struts configuration file name instead of `login.xml` should use `struts.xml`

Instead of `Statement`, use `PrepareStatement` or `callablestatement` to avoid sql injection.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014481/can-i-change-the-struts-xml-file-to-anything-else)

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957489/573032) answer if you want to change the name.

Comment: @Roman C ..i have included the login.xml into struts.xml..in that case ..is there is any issue?

Comment: you can include `<include file="login.xml"></include>` in `struts.xml`. @sufiyan ali

Comment: It will work. Did place in same or in diff loc. @sufiyanali

Comment: @satya ..my question isnt about login.xml ...kindly go through my question.

Comment: @sufiyanali Do you have any errors in the logs? What is the `web.xml` contents?

Comment: <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: @sufiyanali. `filterdispatcher` is deprecated. Use `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` struts 2.3. Add all jars to your lib folder.

Comment: now i am quite close to the result..i am not able to understand that why my code after checking my database isnt giving the positive result after giving same values in my login page as same in database

Comment: did you put return statement after condition true.  @sufiyanali

Comment: while(rs.next()){
         if(user.getEmail().equals(rs.getString("email"))&& user.getPassword().equals("password")){
           return true;}
                   else
         {
              return false;
         }   
        }
       return false;
    }

Comment: don't use `while`, use `if`. one more `if` is not needed (inside loop). see my answer. Its enough. @sufiyanali

Comment: if(rs.next()){
         if(user.getEmail().equals(rs.getString("email"))&& user.getPassword().equals("password")){
           return true;
         }         
        }
       return false;
    }

Comment: after using if(rs.next()) ..the same result is coming

Comment: see my select statement. check with `Sysout` statement whether the values are coming or not. @sufiyanali

Comment: i am quite embarrased to say that i dont know how to query using prepared statement

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/ @sufiyanali

Comment: welll...thnx for ur help and ur time.

Comment: at the end, i end up with desired result ..thnk u Mr.Satya and all those who have helped me