# Not redirecting on wait.jsp page in execAndWait interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2

I want to put processing bar on my page  when requesting is taking too much time to write HTML file. So I used `execAndWait` interceptor in Strust2 , But page is not able to redirect on wait.jsp.

**Struts.xml:**

```
<action name="htmlUtility"          
       class="com.support.action.ActivityAction"                               method="htmlUtility">
        <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
            <param name="delay">1000</param>
            <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
     <result name="wait">/pages/reportingview/ftl/wait.jsp</result>
          <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
      <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${filename}"</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

**Wait.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
 <html>  
 <head>  
 <title>wait</title>  
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5;url='<s:url includeParams="all"       />'">  
</head>  
<body>  
<p>your request is processing...</p>  
<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**ActivityAction:**

```
  private InputStream saveAsHTML() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream printhtml = new PrintStream(buffer);
    String htmlheader="<html><style type='text/css'>.dataTable "
                     + "{width:100%;    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc;+}"
                     + ".dataTable th {background:#f1f1f1;  text-align:left;padding:5px;font-weight:normal; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;"
                     + "    border-left:1px solid #ccc;}.dataTable tr {}.dataTable td { padding:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;border-left:1px solid #ccc;}.txtCenterAlign "
                     + "{text-align:center !important;}.transparentBg{ background:transparent !important;}</style><head>";
    if(activityType.equalsIgnoreCase(SupportWebConstants.ACCESSPOINT_CONSTANT)){
        
        htmlheader+="<title>Access Point Activity Report</title></head><body> <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='dataTable'><thead> <tr>"
                + "<th colspan='9' class='txtCenterAlign'>Access Point Activity Report</th></tr><tr>";

        }
    else
        {
            htmlheader+="<title>Credential Holder Activity Report</title></head><body> <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='dataTable'><thead> <tr>"
                    + "<th colspan='9' class='txtCenterAlign'>Credential Holder Activity Report</th></tr><tr>";

        }
                  
    for (String columnName : ReportHeaderMapper.getColumnList(activityType)) {
        
        htmlheader+= "<th class='transparentBg'><b>"+columnName+"</b></th>";
            
            }
    
        htmlheader+="</tr></thead> <tbody>";
        
                        
     String tableData="";
     String htmlfooter=" </tbody></body></html>";


     activityList    = activityDTOList.getActivityDTOs();
     ReportHeaderMapper.setData(activityList);
     for (List<String> activityDTO : ReportHeaderMapper.getAccessPointAllRows(activityType)) {
         tableData= tableData+"<tr>";
            for (String data : activityDTO) {
                tableData+= "<td>"+data+"</td>";
            }
            tableData=tableData+"</tr>";
        }
     printhtml.println(htmlheader+tableData+htmlfooter);
     printhtml.close();
    LOGGER.info("HTML file created successfully."); 
    LOGGER.info("HTML activityList size" + activityList.size());
 return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray());
}
```

When I generate the request I got below error:

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action
> com.narendra.stg.Sdg.support.action.ActivityAction and result error
>
> type Status report
>
> message No result defined for action
> om.narendra.stg.Sdg.support.action.ActivityAction  and result error
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is returning "error" as result type due to some reason.

Check why its returning error, May be its failling during method execution before it returns success.

Also add return name as error and redirect to some error.jsp page, Thats what your error says

> No result defined for action
>   com.narendra.stg.Sdg.support.action.ActivityAction and result **error**

Answer (score 1):

Default stack of interceptors needed to execute the action. When overriding interceptors you didn't include `defaultStack`. Try the following action configuration

```xml
<action name="htmlUtility"          
   class="com.assaabloy.stg.support.ActivityAction"                               method="htmlUtility">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
        <param name="delay">1000</param>
        <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
 <result name="wait">/pages/reportingview/ftl/wait.jsp</result>
      <result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
  <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
  <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${filename}"</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
</action>
```

There should be an interceptor that returns a `error` result and this result can be configured globally like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875911/573032) answer.