# HTTP Status 404 in Struts 2 web application and result JSP

Tags: configuration, struts2, actionresult

Here is my set up:

Specs:

Tomcat 7.0.109
jdk1.8.0_11
IDEA20232.5

When I enter the 'test5_5' method of this action, it will redirect to a 404 page.

```java
        if(NumberUtils.notNullEquals(result.getResult(), 0)){//登录失败
            return LOGIN;
        }
```

The corresponding configuration file

```xml
        <action name="test" class="test" method="test5_5">
            <result name="login">${page}</result>
            <result name="reg">${page}</result>
            <result name="doreg" type="chain">
                <param name="namespace">/irdUser/login/opac</param>
                <param name="actionName">opacRegist</param>
            </result>
            <result name="backurl" type="redirect">${backurl}</result>
            <result type="redirect">${page}</result>
        </action>
```

1.I tried to hardcode the path of the page, but it didn't help.

```java
        if(NumberUtils.notNullEquals(result.getResult(), 0)){//登录失败
            page = "/fixpage/schools/user/login/opacLogin_irdxc.jsp";
            return LOGIN;
        }
```

2.I tried to redirect, but it didn't work.

```java
if(NumberUtils.notNullEquals(result.getResult(), 0)){//登录失败
            return "ceshi";
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <action name="opacLogin" class="OpacLoginAction" method="opacLogin5_5">
         <result name="login">${page}</result>
         <result name="reg">${page}</result>
         <result name="backurl" type="redirect">${backurl}</result>
         <result type="redirect">${page}</result>
        </action>

Based on the config file above, I 'return "backurl"; ' in the action to redirect correctly, but 'return "login";' is 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login page is only one in the application and you should *not* use a dynamic result returned from the action which hase a `location` hardcoded in the code. There's should be a getter for the parameter in the `${page}`. Such as

```
public String getPage() {
  return page;
}
```

The JSP file should be contained in the web application folder, after the war file is unpackeged to the server, available to the web application and be in the web content folder. You should not use *absolute* path from the hard drive when specifying location. After the application is deployed the location is use absolute from the context root path.

So put your JSP to the web content  folder and use absolute path from there. The context path is added automatically if you redirect to the login page.

The results that are common for all actions can be configured globally.

```xml
<global-results>
   <result name="login" type="redirect">/opacLogin_irdxc.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```

You can learn more if you read [Global results across different packages defined in struts configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875911/573032).

Comment: ok, sincere thinks. I found out the cause of my problem and solved it .